# Iteratively position spheres with DOM pixels using three.js and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

I'm trying to render a bunch of spheres using a function found from SO to translate DOM pixels to coordinates in three.js world (so I can get the spheres in the same spot as my text).

My problem is that the first sphere is in the wrong spot, as can be seen in the picture below. (The rest of them are positioned perfectly).

[image: First sphere out of place]

This is my code for converting pixels to three.js coordinates:

```
function convertDomPosToThreePos(x, y, camera) {
  const vPos = new THREE.Vector3()

  vPos.set(
    -1.0 + 2.0 * x / window.innerWidth,
    -(-1.0 + 2.0 * y / window.innerHeight),
    0,
  ).unproject(camera)

  // Calculate a unit vector from the camera to the projected position
  const vDir = vPos.clone()
  vDir.sub(camera.position)
  vDir.normalize()

  // Project onto z=0
  const flDistance = -camera.position.z / vDir.z

  // Return vector
  const vOutPos = camera.position.clone()
  vOutPos.add(vDir.multiplyScalar(flDistance))

  // This returned vector is applied to the sphere's position property
  return vOutPos
}
```

To illustrate what's happening, here's some screens of my debugger's watch tab displaying the main values for the first three sphere as they are rendered:

*Sphere 1:* (DOM pixels are `x = 24, y = 200`)

[image: sphere 1]

*Sphere 2* (DOM pixels are `x = 124, y = 200`)

[image: Sphere 2]

*Sphere 3* (DOM pixels are `x = 224, y = 200`)

[image: Sphere 3]

As you can see, `flDistance` takes a jump up from 2000 to 2181 from sphere 1 to 2, when it should clearly be higher than 2181 to start.

And the outputted x-value in `vOutPos` goes from ~0 to -870 from sphere 1 to 2, when it should clearly be lower than -870 to start.

My first thought was maybe a value is undefined on the first call of `convertDomPosToThreePos`, but when logging the parameters on each iteration, they are all defined correctly.

Comment: Any chance to provide a live code example?

Comment: @prisoner849 https://drive.google.com/open?id=13NwaOjoQhY3pNsVhOjHzqTfdjirkgRR1

Comment: code snippet, jsfiddle, codepen etc?

Comment: please, read about [mcve]

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue in this fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/325859/ (can't get the actual images displayed there, but `position` is logged to the console showing the issue with the first planet's x and y position)

Comment: Good job putting all this effort into your question, that jsfiddle clearly demonstrated the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three.js uses lazy initialization for several things, including the camera system (projection matrix). That only gets fully initialized when you first render the scene.

When you calculate the position of the first planet, the scene has never been rendered before, so unproject from the "camera" perspective doesn't work as it should.

The solution is to render the scene once before positioning your planets:

```
function initThree() {

    ....
    // initialize camera
    renderer.render(scene, camera);  
}
```